# PHP pdo register form

Tags: php, pdo

```
 $stmt->bindParam(":password", md5($password), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Displays an error message : `Only variables should be passed by reference in c:\xampp\htdocs\site\....`

please help me to fix it.

Comment: show us some details, may be your full implementation

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of bindParam is a variable reference. 
Since a function return cannot be referenced

```
$encpassword = md5($password);
$stmt->bindParam(":password", $encpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```